# how to link zlib library

Tags: c++, boost, zlib, compression

Hi I'm using boost and zlib filter to compress and decompress data. on the instruction of boost page, it is saying
    if the .cpp file depends on an external library, you'll have to build it from the source or link to a pre-built binary.

I used mac port to install boost and zlib. I include the boost libarary as 
    -I/opt/local/include

my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp>

int main() 
{
    using namespace std;

    ifstream file("hello.z", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
    filtering_streambuf<input> in;
    in.push(zlib_decompressor());
    in.push(file);
    boost::iostreams::copy(in, cout);
}
```

I wonder how to link the pre-built zlib external libarary? it is giving me this compiling problem:

```
mpic++ -o local ods_v2.0.cpp -I/opt/local/include
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::iostreams::zlib_error::check(int)", referenced from:
      long boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::write<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >(boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      void boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::close<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >(boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::_Ios_Openmode) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      void boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::close<boost::iostreams::non_blocking_adapter<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >(boost::iostreams::non_blocking_adapter<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >&, std::_Ios_Openmode) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      long boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::read<boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::peekable_source<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >(boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::peekable_source<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >&, char*, long) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      void boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::close<boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::peekable_source<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >(boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::peekable_source<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >&, std::_Ios_Openmode) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
  "boost::iostreams::zlib::stream_end", referenced from:
      long boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::write<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >(boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      void boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::close<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >(boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::_Ios_Openmode) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      void boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::close<boost::iostreams::non_blocking_adapter<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >(boost::iostreams::non_blocking_adapter<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >&, std::_Ios_Openmode) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      long boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::read<boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::peekable_source<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >(boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::peekable_source<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >&, char*, long) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      void boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::close<boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::peekable_source<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >(boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::peekable_source<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >&, std::_Ios_Openmode) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
  "boost::iostreams::zlib::sync_flush", referenced from:
      long boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::write<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >(boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      void boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::close<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >(boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::_Ios_Openmode) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      void boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::close<boost::iostreams::non_blocking_adapter<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >(boost::iostreams::non_blocking_adapter<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >&, std::_Ios_Openmode) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      long boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::read<boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::peekable_source<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >(boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::peekable_source<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >&, char*, long) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      void boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::close<boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::peekable_source<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >(boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::peekable_source<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >&, std::_Ios_Openmode) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
  "boost::iostreams::zlib::default_strategy", referenced from:
      boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::make_params(int) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
  "boost::iostreams::zlib::default_compression", referenced from:
      boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::make_params(int) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
  "boost::iostreams::zlib::okay", referenced from:
      long boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::write<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >(boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      void boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::close<boost::iostreams::non_blocking_adapter<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >(boost::iostreams::non_blocking_adapter<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >&, std::_Ios_Openmode) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      long boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::read<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >(boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char*, long) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
  "boost::iostreams::zlib::deflated", referenced from:
      boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::make_params(int) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
  "boost::iostreams::detail::gzip_footer::reset()", referenced from:
      long boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::write<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >(boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      long boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::read<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >(boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char*, long) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::basic_gzip_decompressor(int, int) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
  "boost::iostreams::detail::gzip_footer::process(char)", referenced from:
      long boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::write<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >(boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      long boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::read<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >(boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char*, long) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
  "boost::iostreams::detail::gzip_header::reset()", referenced from:
      long boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::write<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >(boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      long boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::read<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >(boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char*, long) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::basic_gzip_decompressor(int, int) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
  "boost::iostreams::detail::gzip_header::process(char)", referenced from:
      long boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::write<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >(boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      long boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::read<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >(boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char*, long) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
  "boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::after(char const*&, char*&, bool)", referenced from:
      long boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::write<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >(boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      void boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::close<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >(boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::_Ios_Openmode) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      void boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::close<boost::iostreams::non_blocking_adapter<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >(boost::iostreams::non_blocking_adapter<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >&, std::_Ios_Openmode) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      long boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::read<boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::peekable_source<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >(boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::peekable_source<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >&, char*, long) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      void boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::close<boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::peekable_source<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >(boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::peekable_source<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >&, std::_Ios_Openmode) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
  "boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::reset(bool, bool)", referenced from:
      boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::close_impl() in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::impl::impl<boost::iostreams::zlib_params>(int, boost::iostreams::zlib_params const&) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      boost::detail::shared_count::shared_count<boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::impl>(boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::impl*) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::impl>::dispose() in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
  "boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::before(char const*&, char const*, char*&, char*)", referenced from:
      long boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::write<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >(boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      void boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::close<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >(boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::_Ios_Openmode) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      void boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::close<boost::iostreams::non_blocking_adapter<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >(boost::iostreams::non_blocking_adapter<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >&, std::_Ios_Openmode) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      long boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::read<boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::peekable_source<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >(boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::peekable_source<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >&, char*, long) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      void boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::close<boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::peekable_source<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >(boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::peekable_source<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >&, std::_Ios_Openmode) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
  "boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::do_init(boost::iostreams::zlib_params const&, bool, void* (*)(void*, unsigned int, unsigned int), void (*)(void*, void*), void*)", referenced from:
      boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::impl::impl<boost::iostreams::zlib_params>(int, boost::iostreams::zlib_params const&) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
  "boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::xinflate(int)", referenced from:
      long boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::write<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >(boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      void boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::close<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >(boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::_Ios_Openmode) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      void boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::close<boost::iostreams::non_blocking_adapter<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >(boost::iostreams::non_blocking_adapter<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >&, std::_Ios_Openmode) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      long boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::read<boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::peekable_source<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >(boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::peekable_source<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >&, char*, long) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      void boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::close<boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::peekable_source<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >(boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_decompressor<std::allocator<char> >::peekable_source<boost::iostreams::detail::linked_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> > >&, std::_Ios_Openmode) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
  "boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::zlib_base()", referenced from:
      boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::impl::impl<boost::iostreams::zlib_params>(int, boost::iostreams::zlib_params const&) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
  "boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_base::~zlib_base()", referenced from:
      boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::impl::impl<boost::iostreams::zlib_params>(int, boost::iostreams::zlib_params const&) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      boost::detail::shared_count::shared_count<boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::impl>(boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::impl*) in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
      boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<boost::iostreams::symmetric_filter<boost::iostreams::detail::zlib_decompressor_impl<std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<char> >::impl>::dispose() in ods_v2-DjDcji.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [local] Error 1
```

and how to build and link boost and zlib library on unix cluster? thanks.

Comment: You should be able to specify -lz on the gcc command line

Comment: @weeo `Ctrl+k` to indent code/command line output.

Comment: @JeffPaquette it is still the same error...I'm using mpi..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't have a compiler problem; you have a linking problem.

Add `-lboost_iostreams` to the command line. You may need `-L/opt/lib` to specify a path. This should give you another linker error, looking for `zlib`. Then add `-lz`.

The final line will look like

```
mpic++ -o local ods_v2.0.cpp -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/lib -lboost_iostreams -lz
```

Comment: with -lboost_iostreams it gives me ld: library not found for -lboost_iostreams   with -lz the same error

Comment: @weeo I've added my guess of the final link line; does it work?

Comment: which one is Lflag which one is lib?

Comment: mpic++ -o local ods_v2.0.cpp -L/opt/local/lib -lboost_iostreams -lz -I/opt/local/include 
ld: library not found for -lboost_iostreams
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [local] Error 1
pal-nat184-130-069:ods_v2.0 weeo$ make local
mpic++ -o local ods_v2.0.cpp -L/opt/local/lib -lz -I/opt/local/include 
 same error

Comment: Hmmmmmmmmmm run (if you understand it) `find /opt -name "libboost*.so"` and post the output. You may be missing the library, and this question changes completely.

Comment: libboost*.a is under my /opt/lib folder

Comment: I figured it out.. the libarary is called -lboost_iostreams-mt...i missed the -mt..thank you so much!!!So I do need to prebuild zlib?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if you didn't have `zlib` installed; everything uses it. `-lz` should link it in.

Comment: yes I built the zlib...so I just wonder if I move to another system do I need to build that, Cuz I did so many experiment,now is running and  I don't even know which one is working now...lol thanks!@Alex Chamberlain

Comment: definitely the right one, find boost_iostream was not as simple as it should be..